# More animations with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

here's my problem... I have this site: [LINK](http://www.noword.it/), the fadein animation of both letters and imgs are stored in the CSS file, while the final fadeout animation is written in Javascript.

After the fadeout I'd like to change the page's background color from grey to black with a fade animation as well, but I've literally no idea how to do that.

If i set more delays the animations seems to not work. Can someone help me?

EDIT:
Here's the code of the whole index page:

http://pastebin.com/wgSz8tEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link href="nuovissimo-codice.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(e) {
           $("#tutto").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
               $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#000'}, 300); 
           });
        });


    </script>

    <title>dyingnow</title>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color:#404040">
  the rest goes here......
```

Comment: can you check the jsfiddle, it should be about your jquery and jqueryui references in the header?

Comment: Sorry for deleting the last comment, I had to write it all over again ;)

BTW, I tried your suggestion but seems to be something i got wrong because now the fadeout animation is not working as well...

I have this line in my header section: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

and i edited my code like this:
window.onload=function(){
    $("#divs").delay(15000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
     $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#000'}, 300);

})

Comment: @xflea can you put all of your code in the original post :)

Comment: Done... sorry, i'm very annoying sometimes :)

Comment: @xflea you need this as well: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` :)

Comment: I edited the post by and put the whole source code of the index... i added the line but still same problem :(

Comment: @xflea check the my answer again, it should work this time! You need to use this `<body style="background-color:#404040">` instead of `bgcolor`

Comment: Yeah that worked this time! Thanks a lot, really :)
That means so much to me!

Comment: @xflea haha it is not a big deal! :)

Answer (score 0):

`.fadeOut()` can take an optional callback function...

```
$("#divs").delay(15000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    // any code here will run after .fadeOut() has completed...
    $('body').css('background','#000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/h2rtLp9q/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('body').css('background','#000');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative written with pure CSS utilizing `animation-delay`. It might be easier for you to tinker with unless you're trying to bind events to these animations.

```css
/* CSS */

body {
    background: #000;
    -webkit-animation: bodyColor 15s;
}
div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: 8s fadeInOut;
}
div div:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
div div:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}
div div:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}
div div:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut {
    50%, 80% { opacity: 1; }
    0%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bodyColor {
    0%, 95% { background: #999; }
    100% { background: #000; }
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```